# Scrolling a browser window with modal window, Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, dialog, scroll

I'm using Drupal 6 + dialog.module, Ctools(Axaj), jQuery 1.3.2, jQuery UI

When i'm open a modal dialog window the scrollbar of the browser is locked. I can scroll that if i use mouse scroll-wheel, but not by clicking or key-up, key-down functions.

What is the trouble? I can't find any block function in code like this:

sites/all/modules/dialog/dialog.js

```
Drupal.CTools.AJAX.commands.dialog_display = function(command) {
    var $el = Drupal.Dialog.dialog,
      o = {},
      overrides = {};

    // Ensure that the dialog wasn't closed before the request completed.
    if ($el) {
      $el.html(command.output).dialog('show');

      // Merge all of the options together: defaults, overrides, and options
      // specified by the command, then apply them.
      overrides = {
        // Remove any previously added buttons.
        'buttons': {},
        'title': command.title,
        //'maxHeight': Math.floor($(window).height() * .8), // HACK // DISABLED
        'minHeight' : 700, // HACK // I've set it, and dialog window automagically adjusted - we need central part with content have height = auto, so there is no scroll bar, and hence no problems with autocomplete popups in dialog windows 
      };
      o = $.extend({}, Drupal.settings.Dialog.defaults, overrides, command.options);
      $.each(o, function (i, v) { $el.dialog('option', i, v); });

      if ($el.height() > o.maxHeight) {
        $el.dialog('option', 'height', o.maxHeight);
        $el.dialog('option', 'position', o.position);
        // This is really ugly, but dialog gives us no way to call _size() in a
        // sane way!
        $el.data('dialog')._size();
      }

      Drupal.attachBehaviors($el);
    }
  };
```

And i didn'y find anything interesting in css files. What's the trouble?

Comment: P.S. browser Chrome.. FireFox and IE r working well. Testing is fun :)